# Ler dados json inseridos em mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

Eu ja vi muitos tutoriais, e todos incluem [] mas este não tem, supostamente está a faltar-me algo, podem ajudar-me ?
Na base de dados está id data, sendo id o código base para cada produto que por sua vez tem um calendário.
eu só preciso de ter o id, onde está por get, eu tenho tudo pronto, mas sem o preço não sigo para o paypal e tem o projecto preso por isto .
Não faço a mínimo de como ler os dados, eu só quero ter o id, que ja tenho e com a data de chek-in eu consigo ir buscar o preço, só quero isso.
se me provarem online que funciona, eu pago pelo script, é urgente e eu nao sei o que fazer .. preciso mesmo disso.
eu so preciso ir a este dados, indicar o chekin por exemplo 2016-06-16 e sacar o preço nada mais.

```
{
  "2016-06-16": {
    "available": 6,
    "bind": 0,
    "info": "",
    "notes": "",
    "price": 878,
    "promo": 0,
    "status": "available"
  },
  "2016-06-17": {
    "available": 6,
    "bind": 0,
    "info": "",
    "notes": "",
    "price": 878,
    "promo": 0,
    "status": "available"
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Não há problemas em não ter `[]`, significa apenas que seu objeto `JSON` possui apenas uma coleção de objetos e não há `array` nele.

Tu podes acessar o valor da seguinte maneira:

```
$jsonString = '{"2016-06-16":{"available":6,"bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":878,"promo":0,"status":"available"},"2016-06-17":{"available":6,"bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":878,"promo":0,"status":"available"}}';

$jsonObject = json_decode($jsonString);

echo $jsonObject->{"2016-06-16"}->price;
```

Veja funcionando no [ideone](http://ideone.com/BKOXQk)

Comment: Acabas-te de me salvar a vida, acredita.
Muito muito muito obrigado.

Comment: Aproveita, dá uma lida no [Tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), assim você entende melhor como funciona o StackOverflow. Seja bem vindo.

Comment: Marcelo, estaria interesado em desenvolver integrações de API ?